# Symfony DOM Crawler: querying tag which matched current item

Tags: symfony, dom, web-crawler

I'm using the Symfony DOM crawler to scrape some websites and one of the issues I'm having is that if I have a scrape target which contains multiple tags, such as:

```
$content['html'] = $crawler->filter('
        #content > div.container > div.row > div > p:nth-child(n+4),
        #content > div.container > div.row > div > h3,
        #content > div.container > div.row > div > blockquote')->each(function($node) {
        $data = strip_tags($node->html(), '<div>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <p>, <a>, <strong>, <em>, <img>');
        return $data;
    });
```

I'm not getting the [p], [h3] or [blockquote] tags in my results (which is correct). However, depending on which tag I've just scraped, I would like to process the result a bit further rather than just returning it.

Is there any way the crawler can be queried to return the tag which the current item was matched against? Basically, I'd like to know whether the current item/tag I've matched was a [p], [h3] or [blockquote] which in turn will enable me to further process the results.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out ... there is a method

```
$node->nodeName();
```

which returns the tag the query was matched against ...